# Can't see the files of mounted disk by command 'ls'

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I monted a disk created from snapshot of a VM ubuntu instance which I stopped afterwards on the root directory of another live VM ubuntu instance ( I checked by

> df -h

) in same project of my GCP, I assume I should be able to find those files from snapshot by command

> ls

but not seen there. Please comment if anything went wrong. 
*A picture attached to show the sdb1 disk which source is from snapshot mounted.*
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you create a new VM instance and attach the disk created from a snapshot?
The VM instance has 2 disk: root disk and attached disk.

For attached disk, you have to mount the disk to a mountpoint in OS level.

You can run command `sudo lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0  10G  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0  10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0  10G  0 part /
```

If your result is like it, the sdb(attached disk) has no mountpoint.

You can follow this document and skip step 4(Format the disk.) to mount the disk:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting

After mounted, you can see the files under mountpoin, for example: `/mnt/disks/disk2`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0  10G  0 disk /mnt/disks/disk2
sda      8:0    0  10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0  10G  0 part /
```

If you want use the disk as root disk, you can specific the boot disk option when you create a instance.

**Updated**
(*Below description: data disk means disk created from snapshot*)

I try to reproduce. Steps:

1. Create a Ubuntu instance A, put some files.
2. Create a snapshot from Ubuntu instance A's boot disk.
3. Create a data disk form the snapshot.
4. Create a Ubuntu instance B, attach the data disk.

Login the Ubuntu instance B, execute command `df -h`

It seem the data disk is mounted as boot disk.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           370M  920K  369M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       9.6G  2.4G  7.2G  25% /
copymods        1.9G   29M  1.8G   2% /lib/modules
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop1       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/71
/dev/loop3       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/77
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/72
/dev/loop5       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/sdb15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1006
```

Execute command `sudo cat /etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
LABEL=UEFI      /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0 0
```

Execute command `sudo blkid /dev/sda1` and `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`:
Because the disks have same LABEL, the data disk is mounted as boot disk...

```
# sudo blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="2f3ad447-cc37-48da-a5e8-d7f16b7f0182" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="854cb5e1-01"

# sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="6e0049f4-3ab4-4981-832b-729bc26fdcd5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5b693d52-63b9-
4fa1-b781-f1062aaa7995"
```

You should see the files in *Ubuntu instance B* like in the *Ubuntu instance A*.

**For check the snapshot content.**

- If you want to use the *data disk* as boot disk, you can create instance with snapshot. Or create a image from snapshot, then create instance with the image. (Ubuntu instance B is the Ubuntu instance A replica.)
- If you want to attach *data disk* as second disk, you can create a instance. Then edit the instance to attach the *data disk*. Use `mount` command to mount the *data disk*. (Ubuntu instance B mount the Ubuntu instance A disk.)

Comment: Hi Bear, I attached the picture and the mountpoint should be the root and I think sda1 was the boot disk when the existing VM instance created. You see some file systems under directories like _snap_, but nothing showed up or restored from sdb1. If you can help to comment.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry I can not catch your point. Could you give more information stared from you snapshot that I can reproduce the problem? Step by step.

Comment: Hi @Bear-Su, I follow this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/615357/is-this-the-right-way-to-change-drives-using-terminal and move to root directory and sdb1 there but it seemed not a file system which could be accessible. My purpose is now to check the files originally saved and snapshot. Any comment or command that I can retrieve those files?

Comment: Hi @BearSu, I added another picture above and welcome to check.

Comment: @Michael C. To access the saved files from a snapshot you need to explore the home folder inside the mount point (which as per your screenshot you were currently in) and identify the appropriate user that worked on your previous VM instance from where you took the snapshot.

Comment: @JamesB Can you tell how to "identify the appropriate user..." in command ? Would you mind answering instead of comment then I can try and respond ?

Comment: @JamesB, I think it's related to 'snap' command so would you help describe more and any reference? I use 'snap --help' but still not very clear and also read the page from [snapshots](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snapshots/9468) on snapcraft

Comment: Hi @MichaelC.H.Wang, I updated my answer and list my testing step.

Comment: Hi @BearSu, I follow your instructions but after that I execute the command 'ls' and still only two directory _snap_ and _tmp_ which were in new stance before, not seen the files from snapshot. So if anything could go wrong? I don't want to keep posting my screenshot so hopefully if you can comment or we can check in private.

Comment: Hi @MichaelC.H.Wang, when you login a new GCE instance and execute `ls` under user home directory, you should have get empty result. 
Are not the two directories from snapshot? Or the files are under different directory? I assume you used the GCE snapshot feature.
Do you try "attach data disk as second disk"?  When you mount the `sdb1` as like `/mnt/snapshot-disk`, you can check the data under `/mnt/snapshot-disk/home/<user>`.

Comment: Hi@BearSu, I don't know why these two folders were in that instance before but I do ensure they were not from snapshot. So I create a new instance from snapshot and use CloudShell (I got problem to ssh it as the same issue with retired instance) and the files were there. Strange behaviour and the ssh issue was the reason I tried to mount the snap to an instance that I can ssh.

Comment: When you created the new VM instance, did you use the snapshot as a secondary disk? Or you tried to create a new VM instance using the snapshot as a boot disk?